# ScrollTop doesn't change during momentum scrolling on IPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, scroll, touch-event

I have javascript-problem on IPad.
The problem appears when you scroll the page and scrolling gets inertial.
Momentum scrolling begins When I lift a finger from the screen.
I create a setInterval loop, but I can't get `$(window).scrollTop()` value.
So there is a period when no event fires - even setInterval can't help.

How can I do something while the momentum scrolling is in action?

You can see the problem on [this page](http://www.amag.ru/catalog/239769.html?asd=1) on your IPad.

I see, this [problem is common](http://andyshora.com/mobile-scroll-event-problems.html). But is there any solution or way of solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Guys. If you want to make sticky elements on your site with ipad/tablet support here is an answer: you can use CSS Property - position:sticky. This plugin - http://wd.dizaina.net/en/scripts/stickyfill/ uses it (maybe something else, I don't know, but it works).